# Группировка объектов по полям. Java

Tags: java, spring, group-by, mapper

Необходимо обработать выборку из базы данных, в которой часть полей повторяются (это должен быть один конечный объект).

List из БД построчно:

```
[
    {
        "fullName": "Иванов И.И.",
        "tabNum": "12345",
        "position": "Мастер",
        "docType": 1,
        "docNum": "12314Z",
        "docDate": "2021-11-11"
    },
    {
        "fullName": "Иванов И.И.",
        "tabNum": "12345",
        "position": "Мастер",
        "docType": 2,
        "docNum": "1231wer4Z",
        "docDate": "2021-11-11"
    },
    {
        "fullName": "Иванов И.И.",
        "tabNum": "12345",
        "position": "Мастер",
        "docType": 3,
        "docNum": "1231dsf4Z",
        "docDate": "2021-11-11"
    },
    {
        "fullName": "Попов И.И.",
        "tabNum": "567564",
        "position": "Слесарь",
        "docType": 1,
        "docNum": "12324314Z",
        "docDate": "2021-11-11"
    },
    {
        "fullName": "Попов И.И.",
        "tabNum": "567564",
        "position": "Слесарь",
        "docType": 2,
        "docNum": "1345331wer4Z",
        "docDate": "2021-11-11"
    },
    {
        "fullName": "Попов И.И.",
        "tabNum": "567564",
        "position": "Слесарь",
        "docType": 3,
        "docNum": "12павп31dsf4Z",
        "docDate": "2021-11-11"
    }
]
```

Надо получить список объектов List:

```
public class ResponsibleUser{
    private String fullName;
    private String tabNum;
    private String position;
    private List<Doc> docs = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public class Doc{
        private Long docType;
        private String docNum;
        private Date docDate;
    }
}
```

Пример:

```
[
    {
        "fullName": "Иванов И.И.",
        "tabNum": "12345",
        "position": "Мастер",
        "docs":[
            {
                "docType": 1,
                "docNum": "12314Z",
                "docDate": "2021-11-11"
            },
            {
                "docType": 2,
                "docNum": "1231wer4Z",
                "docDate": "2021-11-11"
            },
            {
                "docType": 3,
                "docNum": "1231dsf4Z",
                "docDate": "2021-11-11"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fullName": "Попов И.И.",
        "tabNum": "567564",
        "position": "Слесарь",
        "docs":[
            {
                "docType": 1,
                "docNum": "12324314Z",
                "docDate": "2021-11-11"
            },
            {
                "docType": 2,
                "docNum": "1345331wer4Z",
                "docDate": "2021-11-11"
            },
            {
                "docType": 3,
                "docNum": "12павп31dsf4Z",
                "docDate": "2021-11-11"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

У меня получилось это сделать с использованием дополнительного подкласса, определяющего поля группировки. Но мне кажется это решение некрасивым. Может можно хитро применить grouppingBy? Как лучше поступить?

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ResponsibleUserListModel {

    private Long unitId;
    private Long responsibleId;
    private String fullName;
    private String position;
    private String tabNum;
    private Long docType;
    private String docNum;
    private Date documentDate;

    public ResponsibleUserListModelGroupBy getResponsibleUserListModelGroupBy() {
        return new ResponsibleUserListModel.ResponsibleUserListModelGroupBy(unitId, responsibleId, fullName, position, tabNum);
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class ResponsibleUserListModelGroupBy {

        private Long unitId;
        private Long responsibleId;
        private String fullName;
        private String position;
        private String tabNum;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            ResponsibleUserListModelGroupBy that = (ResponsibleUserListModelGroupBy) o;
            return Objects.equals(unitId, that.unitId) && Objects.equals(responsibleId, that.responsibleId) && Objects.equals(fullName, that.fullName) && Objects.equals(position, that.position) && Objects.equals(tabNum, that.tabNum);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(unitId, responsibleId, fullName, position, tabNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Кроме этого, я дополнительно обработал получившийся Map, чтобы убрать дублирующиеся значения:

```
public List<ResponsibleOutModel> getResponsibleUserListByUnitId(Long unitId) {
        Map<ResponsibleUserListModel.ResponsibleUserListModelGroupBy, List<ResponsibleUserListModel>> map =
                responsibleUnitRepo.findAllResponsibleUserByUnitId(unitId)
                        .stream()
                        .map(entity -> modelMapper.map(entity, ResponsibleUserListModel.class))
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ResponsibleUserListModel::getResponsibleUserListModelGroupBy, Collectors.toList()));

        List<ResponsibleOutModel> responsibleOutModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<ResponsibleUserListModel.ResponsibleUserListModelGroupBy, List<ResponsibleUserListModel>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            ResponsibleOutModel model = modelMapper.map(entry.getKey(), ResponsibleOutModel.class);
            model.addDocs(entry.getValue());
            responsibleOutModelList.add(model);
        }
        return responsibleOutModelList;
    }
```

Мне кажется, что я иду не в ту сторону. Надеюсь, что укажите правильное направление).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По приведенному коду есть несколько замечаний:

- не нужно использовать слишком длинные имена -- они только усложняют чтение и понимание
- аннотация `@Data` также включает `@EqualsAndHashCode` -- приведенная реализация методов `equals` и `hashCode` лишняя
- если используется Java 16 и выше, вместо класса xxxGroupBy можно использовать кортежи `record`, предоставляющий более краткий синтаксис по сравнению с Lombok-аннотациями.

Ещё, в начале указана одна структура списка, который возвращается из базы данных, а затем приводится структура `ResponsibleUserListModel` с двумя дополнительными полями `unitId` и `responsibleUserId`.  Судя по всему, эти поля могут быть сразу исключены при группировке из класса/кортежа GroupBy.  Кроме того, при группировке следует сразу замаппить часть полей в `Doc` при помощи коллектора `Collectors.mapping`, и подготовить их список.

То есть, классы `ResponsibleUser` и `Doc` должны либо иметь соответствующие Lombok-аннотации, либо реализации конструкторов/геттеров/сеттеров, либо быть реализованы как кортежи (record)

```java
@Accessors(fluent = true) // без префиксов get/set
@Data
class GroupBy {
    private final String fullName;
    private final String position;
    private final String tabNum;
}

public List<ResponsibleOutModel> getResponsibleUserListByUnitId(Long unitId) {
    return responsibleUnitRepo.findAllResponsibleUserByUnitId(unitId)
        .stream() // Stream<Entity>
        .map(entity -> modelMapper.map(entity, ResponsibleUserListModel.class))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            it -> new GroupBy(it.getFullName(), it.getPosition(), it.getTabNum()),
            LinkedHashMap::new, // для сохранения порядка
            Collectors.mapping(
                it -> new Doc(it.getDocType(), it.getDocNum(), it.getDocumentDate()),
                Collectors.toList()
            )
        )) // Map<GroupBy, List<Doc>>
        .entrySet()
        .stream()  // Stream<Map.Entry<GroupBy, List<Doc>>>
        .map(e -> new ResponsibleUser(
            e.getKey().fullName(), e.getKey().position(), e.getKey().tabNum(),
            e.getValue()
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // или toList()
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, замечания по делу.
Да, действительно, у меня есть еще пара полей, но это особо ничего не меняет.

Я попробовал воспользоваться Вашим примером, получил результат, который меня полностью устраивает. Я так понял подход я выбрал правильный? Определение класса \ record (что по сути, наверное, тоже класс) группировки и применение stream api - groupingby с этим ключом. У нас java 11.0.12, record вроде бы мне не доступен.

Comment: Да, в целом подход (использование отдельного класса для группировки) был выбран правильно, альтернатива -- наплодить кучу вложенных мап, используя вложенные `groupingBy` для каждого поля -- гораздо хуже :)  Если все поля в группировке однотипные, можно было бы  использовать суррогатный `List<String>`: `groupingBy(it -> Arrays.asList(it.getFullName(), it.getPosition(), it.getTabNum()))` , и брать потом нужные поля по индексу,