# Разделить заказы пациента по условиям

Tags: java

Есть коллекция с заказами клиентов.

```
List<Order> orderList;
```

`Order` содержит следующие поля:
id_client - уникальный номер клиента
status - Статус заказа
cito - Срочность заказа

Как можно разделить заказы клиента по условию что если у одного клиента были заказы с одним статусом и cito в одну коллекцию, а другие в другую коллекцию?

Класс Order

```
public class Order {
    private int client_id;
    private int type;
    private String city;

    public Order() {

    }

    public int getClient_id() {
        return client_id;
    }

    public void setClient_id(int client_id) {
        this.client_id = client_id;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите выполнить это разбиение/группировку для какого-то конкретного клиента, или для каждого клиента в списке?  Предоставьте больше информации.

Comment: Для каждого клиента в списке. Скажите пожалуйста какая информация еще необходима? Предоставлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения таких задач удобно использовать Stream API, в котором поток заказов `Stream<Order>` группируется по идентификатору клиента, а затем заказы дополнительно делятся по условию на две коллекции при помощи коллектора `Collectors.partitioningBy`, для которого нужно передать функцию-предикат.

Таким образом, получается мапа `Map<Long, Map<Boolean, List<Order>>>`.

Пример реализации (с использованием Lombok-аннотаций):

```java
// пример класса Order
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Order {
    private long idClient;
    private String status;
    private String urgency;
}
```

```java
public static Map<Long, Map<Boolean, List<Order>>> groupByClientAndCondition(List<Order> orders, Predicate<Order> condition) {
    return orders.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Order::getIdClient,
                    LinkedHashMap::new,
                    Collectors.partitioningBy(condition)
            ));
}
```

Тест:

```java
List<Order> orders = Arrays.asList(
        new Order(1001L, "ok", "none"),
        new Order(1002L, "cito", "asap"),
        new Order(1001L, "cito", "urgent!"),
        new Order(1010L, "usual", null)
);

groupByClientAndCondition(orders, order -> "cito".equals(order.getStatus()))
        .forEach((clientId, groups) -> System.out.printf("%d:%n\tcito: %s%n\tother: %s%n---%n", clientId, groups.get(true), groups.get(false)));
```

```
1001:
    cito: [Order(idClient=1001, status=cito, urgency=urgent!)]
    other: [Order(idClient=1001, status=ok, urgency=none)]
---
1002:
    cito: [Order(idClient=1002, status=cito, urgency=asap)]
    other: []
---
1010:
    cito: []
    other: [Order(idClient=1010, status=usual, urgency=null)]
---
```

---

При необходимости большей детализации список заказов можно группировать отдельно по каждому статусу и другим полям, используя `Collectors.groupingBy` вместо `Collectors.partitioningBy`, соответственно ключом во вложенной мапе будет тип поля статуса.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Можно ли немного описать метод groupByClientAndCondition и его вызов. Что происходит в методе и при его вызове? Со стримами еще не работал.

Comment: Так всё же описано в начале ответа - список переводится в стрим, группируется по clientId при помощи ссылки на геттер `Order::getClientId` -- получится список отфильтрованных по клиенту, который в свою очередь будет группироваться по условию, заданному предикатом, в данном случае через лямбду `order -> "cito".equals(order.getStatus())`.

Comment: А если например нужно группировать по нескольким условиям? Например cito, status. У кого срочные и выполненные например в одну группу, просто срочные в другую и остальные в третью

Comment: clientId, groups - эти данные откуда взялись не очень понял если честно

Comment: Ну наверно надо было предоставить свой код класса Order -- я предоставил свой примерный код.

Comment: Сейчас добавлю свой класс в вопрос.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. cito и status пока убрал. Нужно так: разделить для каждого клиента по type и city.

Comment: Так не пойдёт.  Если вам нужно, выполняйте.  Могу предоставить ещё пример как [группировать объекты в списке по полям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1365984/) -- нужно будет создать мини-класс для группировки.  А если хотите менять условия задачи на ходу -- найдите и наймите фрилансера.

Comment: Пара `(clientId, groups) ` -- это целочисленный ключ `clientId` и значение `groups` (вложенная мапа), см. [Map::forEach(BiConsumer<? super K,? super V> action)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, вы хотя бы скажите откуда взялись поля clientId, groups. Не понимаю.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: И у вас фактически код класса Order не совпадает с требованиями, написанными в вопросе. :)

Comment: Сам вопрос не стал менять. Все же попробую сделать без Stream.. Думаю мне не подходит стрим. Условий много становится