# Разделить элементы по условиям

Tags: java

Есть класс `Item`, описывающий записи в БД.

Также есть коллекция `List<Item>`, хранящая список таки объектов. Записи группируются по нескольким полям:

```
record MyKey(long id, String city, OrderStatus status) {
    public MyKey(Item item) {
        this(item.getId(), item.getCity(), item.getOrderStatus());
    }
}


public static Map<MyKey, List<Item>> groupBy(List<Item> list) {
    Map<MyKey, List<Item>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    list.forEach(item -> map
        .computeIfAbsent(new MyKey(item), k -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(item)
    );

    // отладочный вывод
    map.forEach((key, val) -> {
        System.out.println(key);
        val.forEach(item -> System.out.println("\t" + item));
    });

    return map;
}
```

Добавилось поле `date`, которая хранит дату заказа. Как сгруппировать элементы так, чтобы в одной группе были заказы, у которых разница минимальной и максимальной даты не превышали 10 дней?

Comment: задача не ясна. Вот у вас есть даты, например, `1, 7, 15` - это группы `(1,7)`, `(15)` или `(1)`, `(7, 15)` или `(1)`,`(7)`,`(15)` ?

Comment: Находим элемент с минимальной датой и сравниваем следующие элементы с этой датой. Если дата в пределах 10 дней, то добавляем в эту же группу, иначе в новую группу.

Comment: в таком случае, группа одного элемента зависит от группы другого элемента, а значит вы не сможете определить ключ группы, то есть подход выше не сработает. Чтобы подобным образом группировать, вам надо будет отсортировать данные по дате и идти по ним циклом и вручную складывать группы

Comment: а как это сделать? примерно хотя бы

Answer (score 0):

Напишу код группировки на C#, на java сами переведете.

Допустим, есть класс

```
class Item
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

и есть сортированный по дате массив

```
var items = new[] {
    new Item(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date },
    new Item(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(7) },
    new Item(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(14) },
    new Item(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(21) },
    new Item(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(28) },
    new Item(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(35) },
    new Item(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(42) },
};
```

Тогда алгоритм сводится к тому, чтобы пройти по массиву и закинуть группы в список списков

```
var dates = new List<List<Item>>(); 
int ind = 0;
while(ind < items.Length)
{
    var list = new List<Item>();
    list.Add(items[ind]);
    ind++;
    
    while(ind < items.Length && (items[ind].Date - list[0].Date).TotalDays <10)
    {
        list.Add(items[ind]);
        ind++;
    }
    
    dates.Add(list);
}
```

Вывод на печать

```
foreach(var group in dates)
{
    foreach(var item in group)
    {           
        Console.WriteLine(item.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine("--------------");
}
```

Вывод в консоли

```
22.03.2023
29.03.2023
--------------
05.04.2023
12.04.2023
--------------
19.04.2023
26.04.2023
--------------
03.05.2023
--------------
```

Comment: Попробую переделать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ищете заказ с минимальной датой, при помощи того же Stream API [`Stream::min(Comparator<T> cmp)`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-)
2. Проходите по списку и разбиваете его на две части, например при помощи уже [упоминавшегося ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1502586/386633) `Collectors::partitioningBy`

```java
private static Map<Boolean, List<Item>> byDate(List<Item> items, int days) {
    LocalDate minDate = items.stream()
        .map(Item::getDate)              // Stream<LocalDate>
        .min(Comparator.naturalOrder())  // Optional<LocalDate>
        .get();

    return items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
            item -> ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(minDate, item.getDate()) < days
        ));
}
```

---

Разбиение по количеству дней прошедших от начальной даты:

```java
private static Map<Integer, List<Item>> byDate(List<Item> items, int days) {
    LocalDate minDate = items.stream()
        .map(Item::getDate)              // Stream<LocalDate>
        .min(Comparator.naturalOrder())  // Optional<LocalDate>
        .get();

    return items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            item -> (int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(minDate, item.getDate()) / days
        ));
}
```

```java
List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
    new Item(1, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 1)),
    new Item(2, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 14)),
    new Item(3, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 19)),
    new Item(4, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 30))
);

var groups = byDate(items, 10);
groups.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
```

```
0: [Item[id=1, date=2023-03-01]]
1: [Item[id=2, date=2023-03-14], Item[id=3, date=2023-03-19]]
2: [Item[id=4, date=2023-03-30]]
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, вы в другом вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1502823/Группировка-элементов-коллекции-без-stream-api/1502832#1502832 давали ответ используя computeIfAbsent. Я взяв его за пример сделал разделение. Можно ли в тот пример добавить группировку по дате или лучше использовать Collectors.partitioningBy? В чем их отличие?

Comment: `partitioningBy` делит ровно на две группы -- получается мапа с булевым ключом; `computeIfAbsent` создает несколько групп -- для отдельного значения ключа -- например, если бы вы хотели группировать по 10 дней, 20 дней, 30 и т.д.

Comment: Тогда мне подходит только computeIfAbsent. А как используя его разбить еще и по датам? Можно ли?

Comment: У вас должна получиться какая-то группировка по какой-то разнице между датами, а не непосредственно по датам

Comment: Да, понимаю. Мне нужно на основе record MyKey(long id, String city, OrderStatus status) {
    public MyKey(Item item) {
        this(item.getId(), item.getCity(), item.getOrderStatus());
    }
} сначала получить заказы удовлетворяющие этой группировке, а затем каждую группу также разбить если есть такие заказы, которые по дате превышают меньшую дату заказа. Мне кажется внутри list.forEach(item -> map
        .computeIfAbsent(new MyKey(item), k -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(item)
    ); нужно делать это разделение

Comment: Боюсь все-таки ваш способ мне не подходит, т.к. в итоге в Map<Boolean, List<Item>> будет всего две группы с ключами true или false, но могут быть ситуации когда групп 3.

Comment: Представленное здесь решение с булевым ключом относится к немного другой задаче, а именно делению заказов на те, что попали в первые N дней после первого заказа и все остальные.  Если оно не подходит, то фактически данный вопрос можно удалять, так как в его дубликате [Разделить список услуг на группы в пределах 14 дней](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1508408/) сама задача описана лучше.