# Разделить список услуг на группы в пределах 14 дней

Tags: java, коллекции, group-by

Есть список услуг, например:

```
List<Item>  list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Item(123456789, 01.04.2023));
list.add(new Item(123456789, 14.04.2023));
list.add(new Item(123456789, 21.04.2023));
list.add(new Item(123456789, 30.04.2023));
```

Даты в формате `LocalDate`, но для наглядности указал так.

Необходимо разделить список услуг на группы так, чтобы в каждой группе были услуги в пределах 14 дней. Например для примера выше будет две группы:

Первая с датами 01.04.2023 и 14.04.2023
Вторая с датами 21.04.2023 и 30.04.2023

Я делаю так:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getDate_in));

Map<Integer, List<Item>> groups = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i ->
                (int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(list.get(0).getDate_in(), i.getDate_in()) / 14));

for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Item>> entry1 : groups.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry1.getKey());
    for (Item Item : entry1.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(Item + " \n");
    }
}
```

Но получается три группы ,вместо двух. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильнее разделить на группы?

Использовать `Map<Boolean, List<Item>>` как в вопросе [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1507202/Разделить-элементы-по-условиям/1507257?noredirect=1#comment2704072_1507257](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1507202/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/1507257?noredirect=1#comment2704072_1507257) не подходит так как это решение делить список на две группы, а возможна ситуация когда будет три группы. Например такая:

```
List<Item>  list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Item(123456789, 01.04.2023));
list.add(new Item(123456789, 14.04.2023));
list.add(new Item(123456789, 15.04.2023));
list.add(new Item(123456789, 30.04.2023));
```

Тут уже должно быть три группы.

Comment: 14 дней - это две недели. Подойдет ли вариант с группировкой 1-2, 3-4 и так далее?

Comment: Для первой ситуации вначале вопроса подойдет 1-2 элементы в одну группу, а 3-4 в другую.

Comment: А для всех случаев никак не пойму как реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что вы вычисляете *начало группы* динамически, а не от первой даты отсчёта, то есть у вас минимальное значение *даты* меняется при прохождении по списку, и поэтому меняется количество груп.

В связи с этим использовать Stream API / `forEach` с лямбдой для построения такой мапы нецелесообразно, так как здесь необходимо запоминать некое состояние (опорную дату) за пределами стрима, то есть нарушается требование, что переменные в лямбдах должны быть *эффективно финальными (effectively final)*.

Однако можно просто проитерироваться по входному списку, *отсортированному по дате*, и построить мапу при помощи `computeIfAbsent`.  В качестве начальной ключевой даты берётся дата первого элемента списка.  Затем в цикле вычисляется разница в днях между этой датой и датой текущего элемента, если такая разница не удовлетворяет заданному условию (больше 14 дней например), то ключевая дата обновляется.

Примерная реализация:

```java
record Item(int id, LocalDate date) {}

public static Map<LocalDate, List<Item>> groupByDays(List<Item> items, int days) {
    items.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::date));
    
    LocalDate keyDate = items.get(0).date();
    
    Map<LocalDate, List<Item>> groups = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Item i : items) {
        keyDate = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(keyDate, i.date()) < days ? keyDate : i.date();
        groups.computeIfAbsent(keyDate, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
    }
    return groups;
}
```

Тест:

```java
List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
    new Item(1, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 1)),
    new Item(2, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 14)),
    new Item(3, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 15)),
    new Item(4, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 30))
);

var groups = groupByDays(items, 14);
groups.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
```

```
2023-03-01: [Item[id=1, date=2023-03-01], Item[id=2, date=2023-03-14]]
2023-03-15: [Item[id=3, date=2023-03-15]]
2023-03-30: [Item[id=4, date=2023-03-30]]
```

Для случая `Item(3, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 20))`получится две группы:

```
2023-03-01: [Item[id=1, date=2023-03-01], Item[id=2, date=2023-03-14]]
2023-03-20: [Item[id=3, date=2023-03-20], Item[id=4, date=2023-03-30]]
```

---

Решение с `forEach` могло бы написано при помощи *массива* (ссылка на сам массив будет финальная), но это считается трюкачеством:

```java
public static Map<LocalDate, List<Item>> groupByDaysLambda(List<Item> items, int days) {
    items.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::date));

    Map<LocalDate, List<Item>> groups = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    LocalDate[] keyDate = {items.get(0).date()};
    
    items.forEach(i -> groups.computeIfAbsent(
            keyDate[0] = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(keyDate[0], i.date()) < days ? keyDate[0] : i.date(), 
            k -> new ArrayList<>()
        ).add(i)
    );

    return groups;
}
```

Аналогично со стримом -- будет работать только для последовательного упорядоченного стрима, иначе результат будет непредсказуемым:

```java
public static Map<LocalDate, List<Item>> groupByDaysStream(List<Item> items, int days) {
    items.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::date));

    LocalDate[] keyDate = {items.get(0).date()};
    
    return items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            i -> keyDate[0] = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(keyDate[0], i.date()) < days ? keyDate[0] : i.date(),
            LinkedHashMap::new,
            Collectors.toList()
        ));
}
```

Comment: А могли бы немного объяснить что в цикле for (Item i : items) происходит?

Comment: @SergeyMih, обновил ответ -- это обычный цикл `foreach` для итерации отсортированного списка.  Конструкция `forEach` требует лямбду, для которой требуются эффективно финальные переменные, поэтому я её не использовал с самого начала.  В конце ответа добавил "фокус", который позволит использовать лямбду/стрим, но это "грязное" решение с использованием побочного эффекта.

Comment: Отдельный вопрос, зачем вам нужна именно такая группировка, так как фактически она нестабильна из-за того, что "опорная"  дата может меняться, и соответственно состав групп.  Проще/разумнее было бы группировать по половинам месяца / декадам.

Comment: Дело в том, что List<Item> содержит список услуг выполненных пациентам. Группировка в пределах 14 дней необходима так как все выполненные услуги я упаковываю в один случай в а там требование, чтобы услуги в одном случае были в пределах 14 дней не более

Answer (score 0):

Если дата и окончание периода не принципиальны, то можно использовать в качестве параметра группировки следующую формулу `(номер_недели+1)/2`. Добавление 1 нужно чтобы первая неделя не осталась "сиротой". Тогда в одну группу попадут даты 1-2, 3-4 и так далее.

Способ работает для дат в пределах одного года. Так же следует учитывать правила перехода, когда у первого января номер недели может оказаться в последней неделе предыдущего года.

```java
    @Test
    void groupBy2WeekTest() {
        record Item(Integer id, LocalDate published) {
        }
        var items = List.of(
            new Item(1, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 27)),
            new Item(2, LocalDate.of(2023, 4, 1)),
            new Item(3, LocalDate.of(2023, 4, 5)),
            new Item(4, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 6)),
            new Item(5, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 17)),
            new Item(6, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 23)),
            new Item(7, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 13)),
            new Item(8, LocalDate.of(2023, 3, 26))
        );
        TemporalField woy = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).weekOfWeekBasedYear();
        var result = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> ((i.published().get(woy))+1)/2));
        result.forEach((g,o) -> System.out.println(g+"\n=============\n"+o));
    }
```